# Why can't I access to my data function from my computed property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this in my data :

```
 data() {
    return {
      hello: "hello",
   }
}
```

And I have a computed property like this :

```
computed: {
    serviceHello() {
      return {
        sayHello() {
          console.log(this.hello);
        },
        sayHi(){
          console.log("hi");
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm calling my computed properties like this in my mounted.

```
this.serviceHello.sayHello(); // console : undefined
this.serviceHello.sayHi(); //console write "hi"
```

So I tried to see what is inside `this` but there's only the content from the computed(sayHello and sayHi), I can't access to my values in my data.

My question is, how can I access to the `data` from my computed ? I want the `sayHello` to display the `hello` from my data.

Comment: Why is your computed property returning a nested object with functions? Also the nested functions probably need to be defined as arrow function to have access to lexical this.

Comment: Possibly also related the component's lifecycle https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Comment: I tried the arrow function on the computed but not in the nested function ! Thank you. It's because it's a "service", from angularjs. That's a way a find to reuse it so I don't need to refactor a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just assign `this` to a global variable and use inside the returned function :

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Welcome to Vue !',
    };
  },
  computed: {
    serviceHello() {
      let vm = this //assign it here to a global variable vm
      return {
        sayHello() {
          console.log(vm.message);//use vm here
        },
        sayHi() {
          console.log("hi");
        }
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    doSomething() {
      this.serviceHello.sayHello();
      this.serviceHello.sayHi();
    }
  },
  mounted(){
   this.serviceHello.sayHello();
      this.serviceHello.sayHi();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <h1>{{ message }}</h1>

  <button @click="doSomething">Say hello.</button>
</div>
```

**This works fine but it's not the job of the  computed property which should be used to return some stuff based on other properties**

Answer (score 4):

Your computed functions are wrong. It should be:

```
computed: {
    sayHello() {
      console.log(this.hello);
    },
    sayHi() {
      console.log("hi");
    }
}
```

The way you have wrote it means that the keyword `this` will be referencing to the object context itself and not to the context of the component.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the wrong way a computed property.
Computed properties must return a value;

Try this way.

```js
computed: {
  sayHello() {
    return this.hello;
  },
  sayHi() {
    return "hi";
  }
}
```

and access as this.sayHello or {{sayHello}} in templates.

If you are trying to use a computed Setter you can use as this example below:

```js
computed: {
  fullName: {
    // getter
    get: function () {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName
    },
    // setter
    set: function (newValue) {
      var names = newValue.split(' ')
      this.firstName = names[0]
      this.lastName = names[names.length - 1]
    }
  }
}
```

More infor here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html